# Восстановление ssh/sftp через CMS панель

Tags: opencart

Есть арендуемая на стороннем сервисе виртуальная машина с настроенной в режиме паранойи sshd.service. В конфиге ssh авторизация по ключу, ключ утерян. Так же на виртуалке есть вебморда - opencart 3 версии. Вопрос - как можно получить через вебморду ssh/ftp доступ на виртуальную машину?
ОС на виртуалке Debian 9.0.

Comment: Если машина виртуальная, значит можно через управление виртуальной машиной её перезагрузить и в том же управлении виртуальной машиной через VNC подредактировать настройки grub и загрузиться в режиме восстановления, откуда уже подкорректировать настройки sshd

Comment: У меня нет доступа в гипервизор, я об этом упомянул в самом начале вопроса. Виртуалка арендована на стороннем сервисе.

Comment: в сервис данный написать запрос на восстановление/сброс ssh доступа нет возможности? в opencart в настройках еще данные ftp указывают в некоторых версиях и модификациях.

Comment: Во-первых, не вижу в вопросе ничего про отсутствие доступа. Во-вторых, изменение настроек ssh через opencart - это охренеть какая серьёзная дыра в безопасности (даже две дыры), и если вы такое сможете сделать, то получите много тысяч долларов за нахождение уязвимостей (ну или отправитесь в тюрьму, зависит от вашего поведения)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из коробки **opencart** не предоставляет таких дыр, как настройки **ssh** в админке. Однако **!!!** иногда **!!!** люди пользуют настройки **ftp** для установки расширений из архивов. Невероятно - но факт :)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**!** Если у вас есть доступ к адмнке сайта, то вы либо владелец / уполномоченное владельцем лицо, либо не владелец / не уполномоченное владельцем лицо, каким-то образом меющее доступ к админке.  В первом случае вы решаете все вопросы с саппортом хоста за день. Во втором случае - shame on you задавать здеся такие вопросы :)

Comment: Спасибо, я по итогу подгрузил нужные мне файлы в опенкарт через расширение файла .ocmod, и уже после этого, восстановил доступ к админке через саппорт.